# Filter wp_mail based on content type

Tags: filters, hooks, email, wp-mail

I can current filter the content type of the wp_mail function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
});
```

And I can filter the message content

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', function( $args ) {
    $args['message'] = 'Filtered text here';
    return $args;
});
```

But how can I only do the latter conditionally?

I only want to filter the message when the `content type` == `text/plain`.

I'm guessing there is a super-simple solution to this, but I haven't worked it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `wp_mail` filter runs before the `wp_mail_content_type` filter.

If you're using the *PHP Mailer* then you can try (untested):

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function( $phpmailer ) {
    if( 'text/plain' === $phpmailer->ContentType ) {
        $phpmailer->Body = 'Filtered text here'; // <-- Message override
    }
});
```